# .NET 5 Razor Page OnGet() not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-5

Just a basic Razor page for adding an employee, but the OnGet() isn't firing/being hit when the page loads. I tested it with putting a break point in it at the "Managers = new SelectList" line, but it never gets hit.  What am I missing?

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
 {
        if ((Request.Cookies["Admin"] != null) && (Request.Cookies["Admin"] == "True"))
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            List<Employee> managers = _merchDAL.GetManagers();
            Managers = new SelectList(managers, nameof(Employee.FirstName), nameof(Employee.FirstName), null, nameof(Employee.Department));

        }
        else
        {
            RedirectToPage("../Home");
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

And the control on the page is:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <label asp-for="employee.Manager"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <select asp-for="employee.Manager" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.Managers"> </select>
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="employee.Manager" class="text-danger"</span>
</div>
```

***EDIT***

The page was loaded from clicking the "Add Employee" button on the "Manage Employees" page.

```
<button asp-page="AdminAddEmployee" class="btn btn-primary">Add Employee</button>.
```

That didn't cause the OnGet() to fire. What fixed it, was changing it to:

```
<a asp-page="AdminAddEmployee" class="btn btn-primary">Add Employee</a>
```

Comment: Apart from the breakpoint not being hit, what else makes you think that the `OnGet` method isn't executed? What happens when you try to load the page?

Comment: You can check if you have  `services.AddRazorPages();` in Startup.cs and `@page` in the page.

Comment: @MikeBrind The page loads just fine, but the select control that's intended to show the list of managers doesn't show anything.  If I put the code in the OnPost() after the code to add the employee (what this page is for), the list populates just fine.  Everything else works, but the dropdown list isn't populated in the OnGet().  In the Edit Employee Page, that same set of code populates the select control just fine.

Comment: @YiyiYou, verified both are there.

Comment: Where exactly did you put your breakpoint? Note that in your question.

Comment: @mxmissile  At the "Managers = new SelectList" line.  Updating the question too.

Comment: Place it before your `if` statement.

Comment: Tried.... and then it tried performing the OnPost() when the page loaded.

Comment: Wait a second, you put it *before* the `if` statement in the OnGet() method? Did it hit the breakpoint when you did that?

Comment: I did move it before the "if" statement in the OnGet().  The breakpoint still did not get it, but the OnPost() is firing instead.  No code inside the OnGet() is hit when a breakpoint is put on it.

Comment: How are you hitting the page? Are you clicking a link? Submitting a form?

Comment: Sounds like the page is being requested using an HTTP Post request instead of a GET request.: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

Comment: @mxmissile from a button click.  More specifically:    

<button asp-page="AdminAddEmployee" class="btn btn-primary">Add Employee</button>

Comment: @MikeBrind  Good catch!  Changing OnPost() to OnPostAddEmp() got rid of the post back firing..

But, the OnGet() still isn't being called for some reason.

Comment: OnGet will only fire if the page is requested using the HTTP GET method, e.g. if you request the page directly in the browser or follow a link to it.

Comment: @MikeBrind  You got me in the right direction.  To get the OnGet() to actually fire when the page loaded, since it was accessed from the asp-page button on another page, I had to change <button asp-page="AdminAddEmployee" class="btn btn-primary">Add Employee</button> TO

<a asp-page="AdminAddEmployee" class="btn btn-primary">Add Employee</a> and the OnGet() now gets hit.

Answer (score 2):

`OnGet()` does not fire on a POST request. If you need code to execute in both GET and POST requests, then you can put it in a method and call the method from both.

Comment: I guess the button sends a post, while the anchor requests a get

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is quite old but I just wanted to save anyone from the headache I had recently...

While converting MVC project .NET Framework to Razor Pages .NET 7, I made a 'MVC thinking' error when instead of referencing `@model IndexModel` in `Index.cshtml` page I've referenced directly my model class (+necessary `@using`)

```
@page "{id}"
@using WBTCore.Models.CustomModels;
@model AthleteModel
```

The outcome was, no `OnGet()`/`OnGetAsync()` in corresponding `Index.cshtml.cs` was ever called and page was throwing a null exception for the model.